# Location obtained using Google Play Service is wrong

Tags: android, geolocation, google-play-services

I followed the developer.android.com documentation and created the following code to obtain location using the Play Services. All is well except that when I test the Lattitude and Longitude obtained using - http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=latitudevalue,longitudevalue I'm getting the wrong place.

Since the code doesnot give out any error, I'm at loss as to how to find why Play services is making the error !!

Here's my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements 
                        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
                        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
                        LocationListener{

    //Location Objects
    LocationClient mLocationClient;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    Location mCurrentLocation;

    TextView txtLong, txtLat;

    static final int REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES = 1001;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Getting reference to the TextView
        txtLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLong);
        txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLat);

        //Creating LocationClient
        mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);

        //Creating and setting LocationRequest for Location Update
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        //Set the update interval to 5 seconds
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000*5);

        //Set the fastest update interval to 1 second
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000*1);
    }

    /*@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }*/

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(checkPlayServices()){
            //Connecting the client
            mLocationClient.connect();

        }
    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if(status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(status)) {

                showErrorDialog(status);

            }else {

                Toast.makeText(this, "This Device is not Supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }

    private void showErrorDialog(int status) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch(requestCode){
        case REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services must be installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();

            }
            return;
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        //Disconnecting the client thereby invalidating it
        mLocationClient.disconnect();
    }

    //Implemented by PlayserviceClient.ConnecitonCallback interface
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

        /*if(mLocationClient != null)
            mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
        Toast.makeText(this ,"Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/

        if(mLocationClient !=null ){

            mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
            Toast.makeText(this ,"Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //Get the location
            mCurrentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
            try{

                //seting TextViews
                txtLat.setText(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()+"");
                txtLong.setText(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()+"");
            }catch(NullPointerException e){

                Toast.makeText(this,"Failed to Connect" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(mIntent);

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Disconnected" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    //Implemented by PlayserviceClient.onConnectionFailedListener interface
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connection Failer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    //Implemented by onLocationChanged interface
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Location Changed" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mCurrentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
        txtLat.setText(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()+"");
        txtLong.setText(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()+"");
    }
}
```

Comment: Turn off wifi and try again.

Comment: @323go Tried that. Still gave the same location - Svalbard and Jan Mayen, and trust me, I'm nowhere near there.

Comment: I had a hunch it might have been a wifi-location issue. Sorry, can't help otherwise, as it's likely a local issue.

Comment: @323go I'm going to try directly convert the Lattitude and Longitude to address from the phone itself rather than redoing it via browser. May b that'll throw some insights.

Comment: Seems like a good approach. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text view was displaying Longitude first and then Latitude. The test url I was using in the browser, accepted latitude first and then Longitude. The mismatch took me from one part of the earth to another.
Anyway, its solved.